# mCustomScrollbar click-dragging not working on IE 11 somehow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The scrollbar works good on mousewheel scrolling, but if I try to grab the dragger and move it up/down it doesn't work.

Did anyone encounter this problem before on IE 11? It works for me on Chrome and Firefox, though.

The code is really simple, I mean, I'm not doing anything special, just:

```
$('#selector').mCustomScrollbar()
```

Sometimes i add a few attributes or callbacks but nothing special, none of those work with grab dragger and move.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Forget about it, my library wasn't updated.